# Is high-level android lib for gestures that sends event when ascii char is drawn

Tags: android, gestures

Is there a high level android library for gestures that sends event when ascii character is drawn? So far I has seen only support for low level gestures --- strokes etc. I would like to add a GestureKeyBoardListener that calls back when a character from a to z (upper or lower case) or digit from 0 to 9 is entered.

The Google Gestures android app (http://gesturesearch.googlelabs.com/) converts gestures to characters. Are there plans to make the gestures-to-char code use in it as part of a library that any developer can use?

Answer (score 1):

> Are there plans to make the gestures-to-char code use in it as part of a library that any developer can use?

That is impossible to answer. If it shows up in the Android SDK, it shows up. There are no public plans for anything.

> I would like to add a GestureKeyBoardListener that calls back when a character from a to z (upper or lower case) or digit from 0 to 9 is entered.

Use `GestureDetector` and [create your own gestures](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html) for various letters.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I want to avoid creating gestures for all the letters, if possible. Also, just like there was this graffiti convention for Palm, if there is a standard library then the results will be consistent for all users for all android apps. Regarding plans for extracting gestures-to-char code from this Google labs gem and providing it as a separate library, I was hoping that a googler (or the author Yang Li) will be able to answer. I assume that there are lots of Googlers on stackoverflow. Google has tapped stackoverflow as official android dev support.

Comment: @Babu Srinivasan: "But I want to avoid creating gestures for all the letters, if possible." -- you are not likely to get what you want. " if there is a standard library then the results will be consistent for all users for all android apps" -- typically, in Android, this is handled with a "soft keyboard", installed by users, not via some library added by developers. For example, Graffiti is available on the Market. That being said, you are welcome to make a reusable component with your own recommended convention. "I assume that there are lots of Googlers on stackoverflow" -- in a word, no.